# Django RF, React, Heroku & Amazon S3 - Correct file storage

Tags: django, reactjs, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm using a django backend, which merely serves as an api server (no templates and HTML files are rendered). On the frontend I use react and redux to access this api and render content.

The question is, should I use Django to connect to Amazon S3 and have corresponding `FileField()` or should I instead use React to connect to Amazon S3 and then in my django models use a `CharField()` to store the URL to the file?

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use React to connect to S3 but dont use the charfield to store the url. If you want any kind of authentication on the file uploads and downloads, you should make the bucket completely `private` and store the keys in your `CharField`.

Then by using boto3client on your django application you should generate a `presigned url` for a given key.

So at the end, what you will have is, react will call for a presigned url for a particular file and once it gets it, it will use it to download that file and then the link will expire.

To know more on what are presigned urls and how to use them, go to this link: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3.html#generating-presigned-urls